# How to implement third party library like ZoomChart in NativeScript?

Tags: angular, charts, nativescript

I have a nativescript test project in angular and want to implement a third party library like zoomchart in it. I am new to nativescript not sure how to do it.

Please help me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think zoomcharts is for web only. Maybe you can find alternatives like this one [nativescirpt-ui-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-ui-chart)